# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n^2+5}{1+3n^2})^n$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

I came across a question I couldn't solve. The question is:
Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2+5}{1+3n^2}\right)^n$. (This question is after the subsequence section so they want me to find a sub sequence).

I know by graphing the function (and the answer key) that the solution is $0$ but I don't know how to get there. To solve this I need to find a sub sequence such that the denominator is greater than the numerator but I couldn't find a sequence of whole numbers to make it happen.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? That there's no convergent subsequence?

Comment: I'm trying to find a sequence of whole numbers that converges to infinity and use it to simplify the limit so that the numerator is always smaller then the denominator and then I can get that it converges to 0

Comment: If $n\geqslant 3$, $$\frac{n^2+5}{1+3n^2} <\frac{n^2+5}{3n^2} =\frac{1}{3}+\frac{5}{3n^2}\leqslant \frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: @Someguyalive if $0<a<b$, what can you say about the order of $a^n$ and $b^n$ for integers $n\ge3$? Also, is the sequence $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ convergent or divergent?

Answer (score 2):

Comment:

$n=10\Rightarrow (\frac{100+5}{1+300})^{10}=(\frac{105}{301})^{10}\approx \frac 1{3^{10}} $

$n=100\Rightarrow (\frac{10000+5}{1+30000})^{100}=(\frac{10005}{30001})^{100}\approx \frac 1{3^{100}} $

So it makes sense if we write:

$(\frac{n^2+5}{1+3n^2})^n=(\frac{1+\frac5{n^2}}{\frac 1{n^2}+3})^n$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac 1{n^2}=0$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac 5{n^2}=0$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{n^2+5}{1+3n^2})^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1+0}{0+3})^n=\frac 1{3^{\infty}}=0$